# Erro no C# ao tentar adicionar um componente herdado na ToolBox

Tags: c#, combobox, toolbox

Estou tentando criar um componente que herda de um ComBox. Eu criei o componente seguindo os passos a baixo, o projeto esta disponível em: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74275347/ComponentesProprios.rar

- Sem nenhum projeto aberto >File > New > Project > Class Library (Visual C#) > Name: "ComponentesProprios"
- Apagar Class1.cs
- No projeto "Botão direito" > Add... > Component > Component Class (Visual C# Items) > Name: "ComboBoxEx"
- Em References > Add Reference... > Busca por "Forms > marcar System.Windows.Forms > OK
- No "code" alterar `Component`por `ComboBox` > adicionar `using System.Windows.Forms;` > em `public ComboBoxEx()` a baixo de `InitializeComponent();` adicionar `DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;`
- Salvar e "build"
- Em um projeto WindowsFormsApplication clico com o botão direito em uma aba da "TollBox" > Choose Itens... > na aba .NET Framework Components > clico em Browse.. > Seleciono "C:\Programacao\C#\branches\Repositorio\ComponentesProprios\ComponentesProprios\bin\Debug\ComponentesProprios.dll"

É quando aparece a mensagem e erro "There are no Components in 'C:\Programacao\C#\branches\Repositorio\ComponentesProprios\ComponentesProprios\bin\Debug\ComponentesProprios.dll' that can be placed on the toolbox."

Classe BomboBoxEx
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace ComponentesProprios
{
    public partial class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
    {
        public ComboBoxEx()
        {
            DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }

        public ComboBoxEx(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe uma real necessidade de desenvolver o componente numa *dll* a parte?

Comment: A necessidade é que o mesmo componente esteja disponível para vários projetos

Comment: Benjamim, apaga a classe `.designer` que foi criada automaticamente e tenta novamente.

Comment: Apaguei mas o erro perciste

Comment: Tu recompilou pra criar uma dll nova? Acabei de testar aqui e deu certo

Comment: Sim, se puder me mande o projeto. Eu tentei ate mesmo apagar a pasta bin,

Comment: Cara, posta o código onde tu cria os componentes

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26101/discussion-between-benjamim-mendes-junior-and-jeferson-bueno).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo algumas respostas que vi no **SOen** o problema pode estar no próprio *Visual Studio* e há duas coisas que tem que ser feitas para tentar resolver o problema.

1. Clicar com o botão direito na **toolbox** e depois clicar em **Reset toolbox**
2. Ao invés de clicar em **choose items**, tentar arrastar a dll para dentro da **toolbox**

Comment: Realmente no Visual Studio 2013 em diante a função choose items esta com problemas, mas quando arrastei a dll para dentro da tab do tollbox funcionou sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique que a versão do .NET que fez os componentes é compatível com a versão do projeto aonde queira usá-las.

Por exemplo, não crie um componente no .NET 4.5 e tenta usá-lo numa aplicação do .NET 3.5.

Comment: Acho que a tua frase de exemplo está ao contrário. O componente não pode ser de uma versão **maior** que o projeto em si.

Comment: Corrigido, @JéfersonBueno

Comment: Eles utilizam a mesma versão.

Comment: Refiz seus passos igual, e não vi nenhum problema. A única diferença que eu vi é que estou usando VS 2013, porém o seu projeto está usando VS 2015. Não sei se algo mudou nessa nova versão.